# How can I change the rotation point of the object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, threejs-editor

I put a hamburger model on the site using Three.js. As the site goes down, the hamburger rotates in various ways. In one place, it should rotate around itself at an angle of approximately 45 degrees.
However, it does not take the center of the object as the pivot point, so instead of rotating around itself, it rotates from the upper left corner. How can I fix this?

The bread rotates as I show in the link below. Instead, the rotation point should be the middle of the bread and it should rotate on the y-axis.

[image]

Comment: There's no link

Answer (score 0):

Your hamburger model has its origin not at the center of its geometries Axis Align Bounding Box.

If you don't want to edit the geometry of the burger, you can parent it to an empty group with a local position equal to the offset required such that the pivot of the burger appears to be its visual center (or whatever center you want it to be). Then instead of directly modifying the burger, you modify the parent.

```
const burgerParent = new THREE.Group();
burgerParent.add(yourBurgerModel);
yourBurgerModel.position.x = 123; // Some offset you define
yourBurgerModel.position.y = 123; // Some offset you define
yourBurgerModel.position.z = 123; // Some offset you define
scene.add(burgerParent);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you give an example of this using a model, for example the bread in the gif I sent you (it would be better if you name the model "topbread")
By the way, at first I gathered the ingredients of the burger in a group so that the whole burger could be seen on the screen, but I want to determine the turning point of each ingredient myself.

Comment: I don't  see a gif anywhere @tikhi

Comment: Stackoverflow delete my link because I'm new here the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO6o0.gif
@eli-davis